# Firebase onChildAdded for new data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have a list of 50,000 items stored in my firebase reference, and 5 items have been added to that list since the last time the client was online and listening, which callback would I have to use such that it is only triggered for the 5 new items that have been added?

I have offline persistence enabled on my client with `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`. I have a listener bound to an activity listening for children added to a reference. Everytime the activity is created `onChildAdded` is called for all the data in the reference. Is it possible to make `onChildAdded` and `onChildRemoved` be called only for "diff" between my local cache and the data on the firebase server? Or if that's not possible, then to trigger only those `onChild*` callbacks after the most recent update from firebase?

Comment: Have you already tried using the onComplete callback for [update()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html)?

Comment: From the android documentation, it looks like updateChildren() is similar to setValue(). I don't know how to use that to figure out what I'm trying to do. I've added an example to the question which might make what I'm trying to achieve clearer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Everytime the activity is created onChildAdded is called for all the data in the reference. Is it possible to make onChildAdded and onChildRemoved be called only for "diff" between my local cache and the data on the firebase server?

No, this is not possible. From the [documentation on event types](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types):

> child_added is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path

Now back to your initial question:

> which callback would I have to use such that it is only triggered for the 5 new items that have been added?

That would be:

```
ref.limitToLast(5)...
```

But this requires that you know how many items were added to the list, since you last listened.

The more usual solution is to keep track of the last item you've already seen and then use `startAt()` to start firing events from where you last were:

```
ref.orderByKey().startAt("-Ksakjhds32139")...
```

You'd then keep the last key you've seen in shared preferences.

Similarly you can keep the last time the activity was visible with:

```
long lastActive = new Date().getTime();
```

Then add a `timestamp` with `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to each item and then:

```
ref.orderByChild("timetstamp").startAt(lastActive+1)...
```

Comment: Would this solution also fire childChanged and childRemoved events?

Comment: Although Frank's answer is ABSOLUTELY CORRECT, I think you should reconsider the logic in order to handle CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE (based on the actions he suggests). It looks to me that you may consider a Firebase based FIFO journal of C(R)UD actions (with expiration / eviction logic) in order to catch everything that happened when different devices were off-line.

Comment: Yes, a FIFO of events since last query would be optimal, but it looks like I'm going to use a childEventListener as is. When capturing events, I'll ignore data that has already been seen by storing it locally.

Comment: What about deleted items when off-line?

Comment: I'm not sure how, but the onChildRemoved seems to fires correctly. I kill all processes on my android phone (application should no longer be listening to firebase), delete an item from the list using my firebase app dashboard, start the application on my phone and navigate to the relevant activity. The item I deleted appears for a second before disappearing from the list. I'm okay with this behavior for now because data would be deleted very rarely from this particular list, RC & U are the main use cases.

I guess I should write some extensive tests though to really understand what's happening

Comment: When you re-connect to the Firebase server, it synchronizes the current state of any data that has changed. The client then fires the corresponding `child_` and `value` events to ensure your view of the world is up-to-date with the server again.

Comment: Yes, I did multiple edits, added and deleted the same data multiple times and it called onChildChanged once. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct: Firebase synchronizes state, not state changes. If you want to ensure that each client learns of every state change, you should store the actual state changes in the database.

Comment: I liked your last solution but what about the time differences between server and the local device?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [on('child_changed')](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html). Normally, `on()` is used to listen for data changes at a particular location. However, `on('child_changed')` notifies you

> when the data stored in a child (***or any of its descendants***) changes.

It will pass a data snapshot to the callback that contains the new child contents. Keep in mind that a single `child_changed` event may potentially represent multiple changes to the child.

Comment: Wouldn't he in this case get a list of all 50000 + 5 items not he 5 he is asking for (see the last paragraph of the question).

Comment: You're right, I suppose he could also use [limitToLast(x)](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limittolast.html) to get the last X updated children.